# Take newest directory in root path

Tags: python

I want to find the newest `directory` in root `directory`:

Currently this code finds all `directories` in root path and also finds modified `time`:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

root = r'D:\drivers'

def totimeformat(tm):
    return tm.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

dirs = []
for dir in directories:
    d = os.path.join(root, dir)
    if os.path.isdir(d):
        print(d + '' + totimeformat(datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getatime(d))))
        dirs.append(d)
```

Comment: keep timestamp and path as tuple `(timestamp, path)` in `dirs` and then you can use `sorted(dirs)`

Comment: Can i have code example ?

Comment: dirs.append((d,os.path.getatime(d))). and then sort by time

Comment: use `dirs.append( (os.path.getatime(d), d) )` in your code and after `for` loop `sorted(dirs)[-1]` to get the newest  pair `(timestamp, dirname)`

Comment: One other note, unimportant to the posted answers of course...Do you really want to be using access time?  Usually "newest" means a check of either creation or modification time, not access time.  This is of course, a trivial change if desired.  Just sayin'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os.scandir` to get all the information of all the files in the given directory in one system call for much better efficiency, and use the `max` function with a key function that returns the modified time of a given to find the directory with the newest modified time:

```
os.path.join(root, max((f for f in os.scandir(root) if f.is_dir()), key=lambda f: f.stat().st_mtime).name)
```

Comment: How can i have the full path and not only folder name ?

Comment: You can use `os.path.join` to join it with `root`. I've updated my answer accordingly then.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is mostly good as is.  You just need to change it to reflect the logic you describe:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

root = r'D:\drivers'

def totimeformat(tm):
    return tm.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

dirs = []
newestdir = None
newesttime = 0
for dir in directories:
    d = os.path.join(root, dir)
    if os.path.isdir(d):
        t = os.path.getatime(d)
        if t > newesttime:
            newestdir = d
            newesttime = t
print(newestdir + '' + totimeformat(datetime.fromtimestamp(newesttime)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create list with tuples `(timestamp, dir)` and use `sorted()` to sort by timestamp.

After sorting: first element is the oldest dir, last element is the newest dir.

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

def totimeformat(tm):
    return tm.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

root = r'D:\drivers'

dirs = []
for dir in os.listdir(root):
    d = os.path.join(root, dir)
    if os.path.isdir(d):
        dirs.append( (os.path.getatime(d), d) )

newest = sorted(dirs)[-1]
oldest = sorted(dirs)[1]

print(newest[1] + '' + totimeformat(datetime.fromtimestamp(newest[0])))
print(oldest[1] + '' + totimeformat(datetime.fromtimestamp(oldest[0])))
```

You can also get three the newest dirs `sorted(dirs)[-3:]`

Comment: If you can use the created lists for any other purpose, doing this makes sense.  Otherwise, you're doing extra work here just to throw most of it away.  If you only want the newest (and possibly oldest) files to be noted, there's no reason to not just iterate over the list (which you're doing anyway) and gather the specific information you're interested in more cheaply.

Comment: If there's not a performance issue here (that would depend in the size of your directory list), then assuming each answer here works as advertised, the choice really comes down to style...what code do you like and understand best and what will future readers find easiest to approach.